# GAS Execution API エラー 「Script function not found: test」

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Google Apps ScriptのExecution APIでJavaScriptからGAS関数を呼び出せるようにしました。認証は完了したのですが、いざ実行しようとすると「Script function not found: test」というエラーメッセージが帰ってきます。スクリプト内にtest(text)という関数が存在するにもかかわらず実行できません。どうすればいいんでしょうか 教えてください。

Apps Script

```
function text(text) {
  return ("RETURN: "+text);
}
```

JavaScript

```
function request() {
  var op = gapi.client.request({
    'root': 'https://script.googleapis.com',
    'path': 'v1/scripts/'+<ここにAPI_IDを入力>+':run',
    'method': 'POST',
    'body': {'function':'test'}
  });
  op.execute(function(resp) {
    if(resp.error) {
      alert(resp.error.details[0].errorMessage);
    }
    else {
      alert("Success");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

もし質問中の Apps Script のコードが実際に使われているものと一字一句相違ないなら、`function` の後の `text` は `test` の間違いだと思われます。

Comment: すみません、実際のスクリプトでは `function test(text) ` です。